# Extending a 2d matrix

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I have input matrix maze[3][3] as

```
asd
usd
psd
```

and I want to convert it into two matrix mazeW[3][4] and mazeE[3][4] of form

```
Wasd 
Wusd
Wpsd
```

and

```
asdE
usdE
psdE
```

How should I do it??
I tried this but not helping

```
for(int i=0;i<row;i++)
{
strcpy("W",strcpy(mazeW[i],maze[i]));
strcpy(strcpy(mazeE[i],maze[i]),"E");
}
```

Comment: C or C++? Please pick ONE.

Comment: Perferable is C but even C++ may do :)

Comment: You're going to get radically different answers from the C++ respondents, e.g. "use std::vector" or class implementations that use copy constructors to do the work unless you're more explicit and say "I want to know to copy array elements[0..N] into a similar array where they will occupy positions [1..1+N]". They'll be right, since those will be the correct ways to do it in C++.

Comment: Also, based on the number of "not working for you" results, you need to post more of your code in the form of an [sscce](http://sscce.org/). You might want to use an online code-share like [ideone](http://ideone.com/)

Comment: I am seeking a C answer only.

Comment: Ok, posted a complete working answer along with some explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    mazeW[i][0] = 'W';  //sets the first element of each line to W
    memcpy(&mazeW[i][1], maze[i], sizeof(char)*3);   //copies the rest of the line from maze

    mazeE[i][3] = 'E';  // sets the last element of each line to E
    memcpy(&mazeE[i][0], maze[i], sizeof(char)*3);  ////copies the beggining of the line from maze
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(char)==1` you can simply use 3.

Comment: Well, it worked for me. How **exactly** didn't it work for you?

Comment: take a 3X3 input containg all different character and try

Comment: Ok, I'll edit the answer, but still, you should be able to figure this out by yourself, since it's a minor problem....

Comment: @fvdalcin I read about memcopy of cplusplus.com but did not how could i use it in this case.

Comment: Ok, the answer works now. You should take a look at how arrays are stored in memory. `memcpy(&mazeW[i][1], maze[i], sizeof(char)*3);` copies 3 contiguous memory bytes from maze[i] (the line you want) to mazeW[i][1] (the line you want, but skipping the first character)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `strcpy` function, your source string must terminate with '\0',
Seems like in your code maze[3][3] is not intended to be a array of strings as there is no space reserved for '\0'.

In that case you cat use `strcpy` function instead use `memcpy` where you can provide the size of memory to be copied.

```
for ( i=0; i < row; i++ )
{
    mazeW[i][0] = 'W';
    memcpy ( mazeW[i]+1, maze[i], 3); 

    mazeE[i][3] = 'E';
    memcpy ( mazeE[i], maze[i], 3);
}
```

Comment: The problem was that each time we were copying from whole maze array whereas we need to copy from each row of maze array. Do refer to @fvdalcin answer. Thanks to both of you

Answer (score 1):

Without having more of your source posted, it looks and sounds like you are confusing arrays and strings.

In C and C++ a 'char' is an 8-bit value that is usually used to store an ASCII character. The ASCII table is like the periodic table, it provides a numbered list of things so that you can refer to them numerically. 1 in the periodic table is Hydrogen, it is element 1. In ASCII the value 32 represents the space character, the value 48 represents the '0' character, 49 represents '1'.

In C and C++ the convention is that if a sequence of characters are supposed to be treated as a string, they must end with a character that has the ASCII value of 0 (not '0', but 0, also written '\0').

So store a 3-character string, you need 4 chars or bytes.

```
char foo[3] = "foo"; // illegal. "foo" is actually { 'f', 'o', 'o', 0 };
char bar[4] = "foo"; // ok
```

Because your arrays appear to be char-arrays and not strings, you cannot use "strcpy" etc, you must use "memcpy" or copy elements by hand.

Here is a working version of the problem you are trying to solve, hope this helps.

Online demo at ideone: http://ideone.com/6TcapX

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAZE_COLUMNS 3
#define MAZE_ROWS 3
#define MAZEW_COLUMNS 4
#define MAZEE_COLUMNS 4

static void transcribeMazeRow(const char* source, size_t srcColumns, char prefix, char* dest, size_t destColumns)
{
    dest[0] = prefix;
    memcpy(&dest[1], &source[0], srcColumns * sizeof(source[0]));
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // 3 rows of 3 columns, each is a distinct char. this is not a string.
    char maze[MAZE_ROWS][MAZE_COLUMNS] = { { 'a', 's', 'd' }, { 'u', 's', 'd' }, { 'p', 's', 'd' } };

    // 3 rows of 4 columns, distinct character values, not a string.
    char mazeW[MAZE_ROWS][MAZEW_COLUMNS];
    char mazeE[MAZE_ROWS][MAZEE_COLUMNS];

    for (size_t row = 0; row < MAZE_ROWS; ++row) {
        transcribeMazeRow(maze[row], MAZE_COLUMNS, 'W', mazeW[row], MAZEW_COLUMNS);
        transcribeMazeRow(maze[row], MAZE_COLUMNS, 'E', mazeE[row], MAZEE_COLUMNS);
    }

    // this part is mostly to show the poster the correct way to refer to all elements of each array.
    printf("maze: %c%c%c, %c%c%c, %c%c%c\n",
            maze[0][0], maze[0][1], maze[0][2],
            maze[1][0], maze[1][1], maze[1][2],
            maze[2][0], maze[2][1], maze[2][2]      );
    printf("mazeW: %c%c%c%c, %c%c%c%c, %c%c%c%c\n",
            mazeW[0][0], mazeW[0][1], mazeW[0][2], mazeW[0][3],
            mazeW[1][0], mazeW[1][1], mazeW[1][2], mazeW[1][3],
            mazeW[2][0], mazeW[2][1], mazeW[2][2], mazeW[2][3]      );
    printf("mazeE: %c%c%c%c, %c%c%c%c, %c%c%c%c\n",
            mazeE[0][0], mazeE[0][1], mazeE[0][2], mazeE[0][3],
            mazeE[1][0], mazeE[1][1], mazeE[1][2], mazeE[1][3],
            mazeE[2][0], mazeE[2][1], mazeE[2][2], mazeE[2][3]      );

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
maze: asd, usd, psd
mazeW: Wasd, Wusd, Wpsd
mazeE: Easd, Eusd, Epsd
```

Comment: I had got a complier waring regarding character array and string mixup but I never knew of **memcpy** until now